# Replace resource in PE EXE file via script/command line under linux

Tags: python, linux, embedded-resource, portable-executable

I am trying to find a way to **replace contents of a resource "file"** (new resource content can be different size) located in **.rsrc** directory inside of a **PE EXE** file under the **linux command line**.

There is a great Python-based project called **pefile** (https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile).

There is also a **Usage Examples** page (https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile/blob/wiki/UsageExamples.md#introduction) but I can't find an example script showing how to replace contents of the resource file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks, Dmitry.

Comment: Have you tried the [resource editing example](https://code.google.com/p/pefile/wiki/ReadingResourceStrings)?

Answer (score 2):

The Python package [pe-tools](https://github.com/avast/pe_tools) ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pe-tools/)) has a nicely documented command `peresed` that does this.

`peresed --apply RES` allows you to "apply a custom .res file, overwrite any matching resource entries.

You can also edit specific version-info fields or set resource entries to the contents of a file:

`peresed --set-version "FileDescription=My very own file"`